# Chrome extension with iframe: Domains, protocols and ports must match

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, cross-domain, content-security-policy

Manifesto version 2 and his new content_security_policy is now necessary for chrome extension.
I read some docs about 'sandbox mode" which seems to be a workaround for inline javascripts, but I still have a big issue.

After some refactoring, I got the following error:
"Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL chrome-extension://mafcgphdkdbjlngfndodameheehmfhac/eventpage.html from frame with URL chrome-extension://mafcgphdkdbjlngfndodameheehmfhac/DCE24DB153A80B735442BF97F168AE6C.cache.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

I can't understand why 2 files from the same extension doesn't have the same "Domains, protocols and ports"!

NB: Here is a part of my manifesto:

```
"permissions": [
        "http://*/",
        "tabs"
    ],
  "background": {
    "page": "eventpage.html",
    "persistent": false
  },
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": [
        "sandbox.html",
        "DCE24DB153A80B735442BF97F168AE6C.cache.html"
    ]
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sandboxed pages are allowed to bypass the extension's Content Security Policy in part because sandboxing forces them into a unique origin. They don't have access to the extension's special APIs, nor can they grab its data.

http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/sandboxingEval.html offers a description of the workflow we'd suggest you use with sandboxed pages. In short, you'll need to replace direct access between the frame and its parent with `postMessage`-based communication.